# Adding an @ symbol before a string in C#

Tags: c#, file, path, symbols

Within a console application, several parameters are passed. One of which is a file path. This works fine, except when the path contains spaces. The workaround for having spaces within a file name is to have an `@` symbol before, such as `@"folder f/file.exe"`
How can I add the `@` symbol to the `args[4]` parameter like so?

```
boot = new Main(args[2], args[3], args[4], (args.Length == 5) ? "" : args[5], args[args.Length - 1].Equals("-r"));
```

I have tried the following but it did not work for me.

```
boot = new Main(args[2], args[3], @"" + args[4], (args.Length == 5) ? "" : args[5], args[args.Length - 1].Equals("-r"));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are passing agrument at runtime use quotes to "close" its value within:

`C:\your_console_application "arg_1_value" "arg 2 value"`

this will be exctracted inside appliaction as:

args[0] -> arg_1_value

args[1] -> arg 2 value

Comment: This was the issue, I am now trying to get this result when calling from another app. Which I will do after my break brb.

Comment: This is the solution and should be bumped to the top.

Answer (score 2):

it's not the argument you need to change, but the string you feed to it:

```
private void myMethod(string input){

}
myMethod(@"hello");
```

Comment: @MartinMeli The `@` is a C# syntax feature, not a shell syntax feature. Leave off the `@` there.

Comment: I was, but then whatever comes after a space character is considered a new string, being shell. I will pass it with just double quotes instead

Comment: @MartinMeli No, keep the quotes but not the `@`.

Comment: Success! I shall try to replicate the result form the external application which is calling this secondary app.

Answer (score 2):

The `@` symbol in front of strings is only a syntax feature that changes how the string literal is interpreted. It only affects the actual literal it is in prepended to, making it a *verbatim string literal*. It will only affect how the string literal is parsed, but has no further effect on the string object that is being created. Every verbatim string literal has an equivalent non-verbatim string literal that would create the *same* string object. For example, the verbatim string literal `@"\xy"` is equivalent to the string literal `"\\xy"`.

In your case, the verbatim string literal is `@""` which is already equivalent to the other empty string literal `""`. The `@` has no effect there.

Verbatim string parsing also only affects certain characters which would have to be escaped within normal string literals. For those characters, they are interpreted literally, so you do not need to ecape them.

For spaces however, there is no effect, so you wouldn’t need to use verbatim string literals in the first place. As long as you pass the path as a single string, it should work just fine.